# Halt while loop if the condition is not met

Tags: c, while-loop

I'm trying to add a while loop inside the program. After it executes it's supposed to ask you if you want to continue and type in "y" if you do and "n" if you don't. If they do it's supposed to start over again, if not then it stops.

The thing is I wanted to make a message pop up if someone types in something other then "y" or "n" to require them to do that. The problem is the while loop will go on whatever they write in.

```
char cnd[100];

while(cnd[0] != 'n') {

    printf("Program executing\n");

    printf("Would you like to launch the program again? If not then type in 'n', if you do then type in 'y': ");
    scanf("%s", &cnd);

    while(cnd[0] != 'n' || cnd[0] != 'y') {
        printf("You have to type in either 'y' or 'n':");
        scanf("%s", &cnd);
    }

}

return 0;
```

I tried to even test this by printing the user input before and after the statement. It does seem to be correct, so I don't know why the while loop won't work.

Comment: Well the thing is I just wanted to always be open to maybe changing it to "yes" for example. Then it would require a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's translate your loop condition to plain English:

`cnd[0] != 'n' || cnd[0] != 'y'`

Basically, you're saying:

> If the first character in `cnd` is something other than `n`, **or** the first character in `cnd` is something other than `y`, enter the loop.

This is unfalsifiable since `cnd[0]` will always be either not `n` or not `y` - it can't be both at the same time.

You should instead be asking:

> If the first character in `cnd` is something other than `n`, **and** the first character in `cnd` is something other than `y`, enter the loop.

Answer (score 1):

your while loop checks if it isn't y or isn't n one of those is always true try this instead

```
while(cnd[0] != 'n' && cnd[0] != 'y') {
```

Answer (score 1):

The condition `cnd[0] != 'n' || cnd[0] != 'y'` is *always* true. You meant to use `&&` (logical and).

You also need to drop `&` from `&cnd` (in both `scanf` calls) as that'd result in format specifier mismatch.

Also in the very first iteration `cnd` is uninitialized. You're better off using a `do ..while` loop or start `cnd` with "y" such as: `char cnd[100] = "y";`

[Note the problems with `scanf` too.](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html)

Answer (score 1):

read what you wrote (as code, not as english)

```
while(cnd[0] != 'n' || cnd[0] != 'y') {
```

if cnd[0] = 'n' then it doesnt = 'y' and vice versa.

you mean

```
while(cnd[0] != 'n' && cnd[0] != 'y') {
```

ie give the error is its not n and its not y

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost: Why do you read a string when you want a single character? Use getchar(). Then check if there is other garbage after that character in the stream and act accordingly: Error message, clearing stdin:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void clear(FILE *stream)
{
    int ch;
    // eat everything until a newline or EOF is encountered:
    while ((ch = fgetc(stream)) != EOF && ch != '\n');
}

bool only_whitespace(FILE *stream)
{
    int ch;
    // eat all whitespace until a newline or EOF is encountered:
    while ((ch = fgetc(stream)) != EOF && isspace((char unsigned)ch) && ch != '\n');
                                                // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ don't pass signed values
                                                // to the functions from <ctype.h>
    if (ch == '\n') {  // when the last character read was a newline
        ungetc(ch, stream);  // put it back into the stream
        return true;         // and tell the caller that all we encountered
    }                        // was whitespace
    return false;
}

int main(void)
{
    int again;

    do {
        puts("Program executing\n");

        while (printf("Would you like to launch the program again? If not then type in 'n', if you do then type in 'y': "),
               (again = getchar()) != EOF && again != 'y' && again != 'n' || !only_whitespace(stdin))
        {
            fputs("Input error!\n\n", stderr);
            if (again != '\n')  // when the character read was not a newline
                clear(stdin);   // there could be other garbage left in the stream
        }
        clear(stdin);

    } while (again == 'y');

    // return 0;  // Since C99 (i think) the effect of execution reching the end of main() without
                  // encountering a return-statement is the same as return 0; (same in C++)
}
```